# Flutter : Disable Android UI

Tags: android, flutter

how can I disable Android features when I launch my Flutter app?
I don't want to juste hide it, I don't want the user to be able to escape the app (it is for a kiosk).
Thank you in  advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SOF.

You should use native Android code, there is no Kiosk mode package for Flutter, now.

You may use tutors like this : http://www.valentinourbano.com/Android-Kiosk-App.html